# Why does Flask app not support POST request?

Tags: python, html, http, flask, post

I'm relatively new to front end development, so any advice would be much appreciated. I am trying to have an HTTP server hosting an HTML webpage send a POST request to a Flask app, but I am running into the error

```
Error response
Error code: 501

Message: Unsupported method ('POST').

Error code explanation: HTTPStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED - Server does not support this operation.
```

I don't have issues making cURL post requests to my flask application or get requests to my flask application from the HTML webpage, but for some reason I can't make a POST request from the HTML webpage.

Here's my test HTML webpage I am running using **python3 -m http.server 8080**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Click me</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/login">
            <label for="user">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="user" name="user" required>
        
            <label for="password">Email:</label>
            <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" required>
        
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the corresponding flask app I am running with **python3 app.py**:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    user = str(request.form.get("user"))
    password = str(request.form.get("password"))
    return jsonify({"message": "successfully posted"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="localhost", port=8080)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do POST request in Flask, you are missing the HTTP status code.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/example', methods=['POST'])
def example():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Access the data sent in the request
        data = request.get_json()

        # Process the data
        # ...

        # Return a response
        return 'Success', 200
    else:
        return 'Method not allowed', 405

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```